# Regex for comma or/and white space separation

Tags: regex

What would be the regex for separating a string into a list of items based on comas and/or white spaces?

Example:
`"item1, item2 item3    item4 , item5"`

Result: `["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]`

Comment: Show us more inputs and desired outputs. Also your attempt...

Comment: Also please review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) and [edit] accordingly (viz. update language tags etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex `[,\s]+` to find your delimiters.

Here is an example on python:

```
import re
text = "item1, item2 item3    item4 , item5"
result = re.split(r'[,\s]+', text)
```

This code return the following output:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you want but I would do it in python with the following piece of code using a regex to split the string :

```
import re
s="item1, item2 item3    item4 , item5"
re.split('\s*,*\s*',s)
```

Gives as output :

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

`item\d+`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TU8R1C/2)